# Panda não cria novas linhas em Planilha

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-excel, pandas

Ao criar o programa em Python eu pego algumas informações e as coloco dentro de uma Lista.

Ao tentar escrever esta lista em um arquivo de excel os dados acabam ficando todos no mesmo bloco sem criar novas linhas.

Como faço para esses dados criarem novas linhas com a virgula como separação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver ele não cria novas linhas, os dados da minha lista estão todos separados por virgula, mas o Pandas não esta criando novas linhas.

Segue o codigo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME':[Lawyer_Name],'OAB':[Lawyer_OAB]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('OABScrapperExcel.xlsx',engine = 'xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='LIST OF LAWYERS')

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui reproduzir o problema com uma lista válida, o seguinte funciona:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['Pedro', 'Joaquim'],'OAB':['123', '321']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('OABScrapperExcel.xlsx',engine = 'xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='LIST OF LAWYERS')

writer.save()
```

O que acredito que esteja acontecendo é que você não tem listas, mas sim uma string JSON pra cada um dos campos.

Assim, poderia ser consertado carregando os JSON e os transformando em listas:

```
import json
...
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': json.loads(Lawyer_Name),'OAB':json.loads(Lawyer_OAB)})
```